# An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: BIRTHDATE MemberID: 7221705 JobID: 0

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I create a landing page that allows creating a record in Salesforce marketing cloud SFMC and when I fill all the fields and click on "Validate"
an error message appears:

> **An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: BIRTHDATE MemberID: 7221705 JobID: 0**

**this my code:**

```
%%[   
    set @sexe = RequestParameter("GENDER")
    set @firstname = RequestParameter("FIRSTNAME")
    set @lastname = RequestParameter("SURNAME")
    set @email = RequestParameter("EMAIL")
    set @tel = RequestParameter("PHONENUMBER")
    set @langue = RequestParameter("PREFERRED_LANGUAGE")
    IF EMPTY(@date) OR ISNULL(@date) THEN
        set @date= RequestParameter("BIRTHDATE")
    ELSE 
        set @day = Substring(@date,1,2)
        set @month = Substring(@date,4,2)
        set @year = Substring(@date,7,4)
    ENDIF
]%%

%%[
    /* Check to see if a record exists with this UID */ 
    Set @lookUp = LookupRows("CUSTOMER_LOT_6","UID_TARGET",@UID) 
    IF RowCount(@lookUp) == 0 THEN 
]%%

%%[
    /* If no record exists with this UID Insert Variables into the Data Extension */ 
    if TAG_AFFILIATE == 'BE' then
        (UPSERTDATA("CUSTOMER_LOT_7","UID_TARGET",@UID, "FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "PREFERRED_LANGUAGE", @langue, "BIRTHDATE", @date)) 
    else
        (UPSERTDATA("CUSTOMER_LOT_7","UID_TARGET",@UID, "FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "BIRTHDATE", @date))
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: What is the what format is the date been passed to it ?

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY this format

Comment: is this code correct or not :
 IF EMPTY(@date) OR ISNULL(@date) THEN set @date= RequestParameter("BIRTHDATE")

Maybe if I add this line "set @date= RequestParameter("BIRTHDATE")" before the IF??
or i must write only set@date= BIRTHDATE?

thank you

Comment: hello 
I fixed the problem I delete the "IF EMPTY(@date) OR ISNULL(@date)"

Comment: Brilliant. Post the answer